# Call a function in another function

Tags: javascript, function, typescript, server

I have a function `publicRooms` to display public discussions that are on the server. I want to use this data for another function I created `addNewMessageNewThread`:

```
matrixClient.publicRooms(function(err, data) {
  console.log("Public Rooms: %s", JSON.stringify(data));
  console.log("data", data.chunk[0].aliases[0]);

  this.addNewMessageNewThread({
    'id': 'paul',
    'author': 'Paul Manip',
    'body': '  ?'
  });
});
```

Off when I do that, he tells me he does not know this function :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'addNewMessageNewThread' of
>   undefined

And when I test this function outside the function, it works

**///////////EDIT//////////////**

This is my function `addNewMessageNewThread()` :

```
addNewMessageNewThread(objMessage: any): void {

    const newUser: User      = new User(objMessage.author, objMessage.site);
    const newThread: Thread = new Thread(objMessage.id, [newUser],objMessage.title);
    const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);

    objMessage.date = moment().toDate();

    newThread.arrayMessages.push(newMessage);
    newThread.messages = Observable.of(newThread.arrayMessages);

    newThread.lastMessage = newMessage;

    objMessage.thread = newThread;
    this.addThread(newThread);
}
```

Comment: What does `addNewMessageNewThread()` do?  Is it by any chance asynchronous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass the context `this`:

```
matrixClient.publicRooms(function(err, data) {
  console.log("Public Rooms: %s", JSON.stringify(data));
  console.log("data", data.chunk[0].aliases[0]);

  this.addNewMessageNewThread({
    'id': 'paul',
    'author': 'Paul Manip',
    'body': '  ?'
  });
}, this);
```

Or use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to use the parent context:

```
matrixClient.publicRooms((err, data) => {
  console.log("Public Rooms: %s", JSON.stringify(data));
  console.log("data", data.chunk[0].aliases[0]);

  this.addNewMessageNewThread({
    'id': 'paul',
    'author': 'Paul Manip',
    'body': '  ?'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instrad of calling `this.addNewMessageNewThread` try with `matrixClient.addNewMessageNewThread`.

`this` reffers to the callback's context.

If this `addNewMessageNewThread` doesn't belong to the `matrixClient` (guessing), before calling `matrixClient.publicRooms()`, assing:

```
var that = this;
```

And use `that` inside callback instead of `this`.